# How can I get a change to the Model (from within a Directive) to update in the View? $apply?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

There are a lot of questions/answers here on stackoverflow and out on google about this topic (`$apply`), and I feel like I have read every one and followed them, but to no avail. All my searches on google now return purple links.

Here's the issue I'm facing (trying to be specific without overkill):

I have an app which pulls data via a webservice, storing the records in an array. I have created a drag/drop target to upload an excel file with changes/additions to the data. I have created a directive for the drop target, which binds the event listeners to the element. I have isolated the scope, using `&` to bind a function from the controller into the directive. The function in the controller processes the file dropped and updates the model. Here is the setup:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myController as vm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div drop-target drop="vm.drop(files)">
        <p>Drag an XLSX file here to import.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also have a table afterward with ng-repeat to display the records.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myController', ['dataService', '$scope', function (data, $scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = data;
    vm.drop = function (files) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            ... Read and parse excel sheet into array of objects ...

            importLines(wbJson);  //call function to update model with objects
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(files[0]);
    }

    function importLines(lines) {
        //do a bunch of validation and update model data
    }
}
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('dropTarget', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            drop: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, controller) {
            el.bind("dragover", function (e) {
                ...
            });

            el.bind("dragenter", function (e) {
                ...
            });

            el.bind("dragleave", function (e) {
                ...
            });

            el.bind("drop", function (e) {
                if (e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
                if (e.stopPropogation) { e.stopPropogation(); } // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
                var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.drop({ files: files });
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

So everything I have read online seems to indicate that I should wrap my call to the controller function in `$apply()`, as you see I have done. All of the functionality of the drag/drop and updating the model works fine. However, the view does not update. The model is updated--I can see it in the console. And when I trigger any other Angular activity (clicking some button that has an ng-click or checking a checkbox that has ng-change, etc.), the whole UI updates and I can see all the updates to the model.

If I wrap the call to `importLines` in the controller with $apply(), it works great. But my understanding is the $apply() call should be done within the directive...try to avoid it in the controller.

I can't for the life of me figure out why it doesn't work. It seems to follow the literally dozens and dozens of examples on forums and blogs about $apply() that I have read. I am still fairly new to angular--I know I don't fully understand some of the forums/blogs when they start discussing $digest cycles and such (but I know a lot more than I did a couple days ago). I understand that some changes to the model are done outside of angular's context, so you have to call $apply(). Some answers have said that the link function of a directive is within angular's context, others no. I don't get any errors (no $apply within $apply). Everything runs smoothly...it just doesn't update the view.

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

---

### **UPDATE:**

Thanks Erti-Chris for the answer. I ended up putting a `$q` promise in the `vm.drop` function, resolving it after the `importLines` function finishes. In the directive, when I left the `scope.$apply()`, I was getting an error that an $apply was already in process. But I still had to have a `.then` on the function call, even though it's empty. Without it, it wouldn't work right.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myController', ['dataService', '$scope', function (data, $scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = data;
    vm.drop = function (files) {
        var deferred = $q.defer(); //Added
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            ... Read and parse excel sheet into array of objects ...

            importLines(wbJson);
            deferred.resolve(); //Added
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(files[0]);
        return deferred.promise; //Added
    }

    function importLines(lines) {
        //do a bunch of validation and update model data
    }
}
```

**Directive**

```
scope.drop({ files: files }).then(function (r) {
    // Do nothing here, but doesn't work without .then
});
```

It updates right away now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect the FileReader class to be asynchronous. It doesn't make sense that it would block in JS. Thus that would explain why your scope.apply is not working in directive. The reason is: scope apply runs BEFORE `importLines` has chance to run(as it is asynchronous).

You can look into `$q`(a promise object, which will solve it nicely) or you can create a callback function which will "notify" directive that importLines has finally been done.

```
vm.drop = function (files, doneCallback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          ... Read and parse excel sheet into array of objects ...

          importLines(wbJson);  //call function to update model with objects
          if(doneCallback) 
            doneCallback();
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(files[0]);
}
```

and in directive:

```
  scope.drop({ files: files }, scope.$apply);
```

Answer (score 0):

Directives can have an isolated scope or it can share the scope with the parent scope. However in your case you are making use of the isolated scope by declaring

```
scope: {
  drop: '&'
},
```

in your directive. & allows the directive's isolate scope to pass values into the parent scope for evaluation in the expression defined in the attribute. Instead, = sets up a two-way binding expression between the directive's isolate scope and the parent scope. If you make use of

```
scope: {
  drop: '='
},
```

in your directive then it will pass that scope object completely and make use of the two way binding.

You can make use of ngModel in your directive.

```
app.directive('dropTarget', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require:'^ngModel',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, controller,ngModel) {
      el.bind("dragover", function (e) {
        ...
      });

      el.bind("dragenter", function (e) {
        ...
      });

      el.bind("dragleave", function (e) {
        ...
      });

      el.bind("drop", function (e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); } // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
        if (e.stopPropogation) { e.stopPropogation(); } // Necessary. Allows us to drop.
        var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        scope.$apply(function () {
          ngModel.$setViewValue({ files: files });
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```